# How to get the file name of input type="file" inside the servlet for File Upload

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

The action EdgeWarUpload in the below form is a servlet and it is to upload a file.

```
<form action="EdgeWarUpload" method="post"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
        <br />
     <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
 </form>
```

It is working fine but inside the servlet post method , I want the name of the file that is uploaded.I tried with

```
request.getParameter("file");
```

But that is giving me null. 
How can I  get the value of the file name from the form.Please check.

Comment: It is a mime attachment and not a parameter (and that has a name)

Comment: HI ,how to get that name.

Comment: Duplicate: [How to upload file in JSP/Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Comment: Related: [How to get path of uploaded file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3374408)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Servlet 3.0 API

Add `@MultipartConfig()` to the servlet and use this to print the names.

```
public void printNames(HttpServletRequest request){
    for(Part part : request.getParts()){
        System.out.println("PN: "+ part.getName());
        Collection<String> headers = part.getHeaders("content-disposition")
        if (headers == null)
            continue;
        for(String header : headers){
            System.out.println("CDH: " + header);                  
        } 
    }
}
```

For older Servlet APIs I would recommend to use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html)

Comment: Hi @Balint Bako I got the name of the parameter as "file".But I want the value of the parameter.I mean the name of the file that I selected for upload.

Comment: I see, sorry about that, I didn't launch a servlet to test it. Check the `part.getHeaderNames()` and the header values, it should be in it. It should be in the `Content-Disposition` header actually.

Comment: part.getHeaderNames() contains two items.content-type and content-disposition.

Comment: As I wrote ´content-disposition´ should be the name. Get the value of the header value with `part.getHeaders("content-disposition")`. I've updated the answer.